# Get a username from email ID

Tags: sql-server

I have declared variable   @email ,

```
Declare user_name varchar(500)
```

How to pass the vale to username , value is @email=’ragkv@gmail.com’ then user name=’ragkv’ I have to get it from email up @. How to do this? Thanks in advance

Comment: *Very low quality:* What have you tried? Where is your code?

Comment: Side note: looks like you are also looking to get yourself in trouble with duplicated user names if you allow anything but @gmail.com...

Comment: I have list of mail id’s .. for my SP user_name = 1st part of email id . ie.,, up to @ . from that user name , user will log in to application .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So you want to trim the value at the first instance of a character? You can do this by passing charindex() as the length parameter for substring()

```
DECLARE @email VARCHAR(20)='ragkv@gmail.com'
DECLARE @username VARCHAR(20)

SELECT @username = SUBSTRING(@email,0,charindex('@',@email,0))

SELECT @username
```